# AES 128 Encription in SQLSERVER OR ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i am trying to create a web service which needs to return data in AES 128 encryption format. Someone please help me, how can i achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you trying to *weaken* security by implementing your own custom encryption scheme? How are you going to exchange keys? What are you trying to protect? Why not use HTTPS with TLS1.2 which uses *stronger* encryption and works with *every* client?

Comment: AES128 isn't a format, it's an encryption algorithm. The result of that encryption can be returned in various formats. In any case, if by `web services` you mean SOAP, WCF already provides security features that conform to the WS-* standards.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class EncryptionAES128
    {
     static public string EncryptString(string inputString, string key)
            {
                string output = "";


                Rijndael encryption = new RijndaelManaged();

                try
                {
                    encryption.IV = GenerateIV();
                    encryption.Key = StringToByte(key);

                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = encryption.CreateEncryptor(encryption.Key, encryption.IV);

                    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                            {
                                swEncrypt.Write(inputString);
                            }

                            byte[] cipherText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                            byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipherText.Length + encryption.IV.Length];

                            encryption.IV.CopyTo(encrypted, 0);
                            cipherText.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH);

                            output = ByteToString(encrypted);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }


                return output;
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? It won't encrypt the data in the database, that's the job of TDE. It won't encrypt the web service's response, that's the job of HTTPS and TLS1.2. Where is the key coming from?